# Переиспользование модального окна iziModal

Tags: javascript

Есть модальное окно корзины, вызов оного происходит 2 способами.
Из хэдера окно должно быть спозицианировано справа вверху страницы.
Из страницы товара по кнопке "купить" - по центру страницы.
Что было сделано и в чем проблема :
создан класс `centered-modal` с позиционирование по центру, навешан ивент на "купить", при котором сначала вешается `centered` на модалку, потом `iziModal('open')` - все хорошо, но при закрытии этой же модалки библиотека сама стирает класс `centered` и мы видим анимацию того, что она возвращается в прежнее положение, а потом исчезает.
Как убрать это дерганье?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ваш класс участвовал в событии закрытия модального окна, добавьте его в значение свойства `transitionOutOverlay`. По дефолту в нем используется `.fadeOut`, но если вы добавите к нему еще `.centered-modal`, тогда ваш класс будет удаляться только после полгого закрытия модального окна.

```
$('#modal').iziModal('open', { transitionOutOverlay: 'fadeOut centered-modal' });
```

Comment: не отработало, лишних классов на анимацию нет, все дефолтное